# Quit hidden attribute to many files in a directory once in UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, command, pipeline, hidden-files

Hello Everybody there.

I wanna know if there is a command of set of commands (maybe a pipeline set) which can be used to change the hidden attribute of many files stored in a particular directory, with the same name.

ie.

```
ls -la inside torrents/music/david_guetta_greatest_hits shows the next files:

drwxrwxrwx  20 crsuarez  staff      680 Apr  9 19:25 .
drwxrwxrwx  20 crsuarez  staff      680 Apr  9 19:11 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  6894561 Apr  9 19:16 .I'm Famous.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  7543777 Apr  9 19:16 .Gettin Over.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  6378465 Apr  9 19:16 .I Gotta Feeling.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  7245793 Apr  9 19:16 .In love with myself.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  7060449 Apr  9 19:16 .It's the Way You Love Me.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  7737313 Apr  9 19:16 .Love Don't Let Me Go.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  7737313 Apr  9 19:16 .Love is Gone.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  6628321 Apr  9 19:16 .Memories.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  7525345 Apr  9 19:16 .Money.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  7806945 Apr  9 19:16 .One Love.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  7192545 Apr  9 19:16 .Sexy Bitch.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  6954977 Apr  9 19:16 .Stay.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  8025057 Apr  9 19:16 .The World is Mine.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  7769057 Apr  9 19:16 .TitaniuM.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  6693857 Apr  9 19:16 .Turn ME ON.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  7215073 Apr  9 19:16 .When Love Takes Over.wma
-rw-r--r--   1 crsuarez  staff  8182753 Apr  9 19:16 .Without YoU.wma
```

I wanna unhide all of this files with a single set of commands (I don't care if I have to use pipeline), instead of use `mv .hidden_file_name not_hidden_file_name`.

The solution must be OSX Complain. ;)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "hidden attribute". What you seem to want to do is rename the files so that their names don't start with `.`. See [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams)'s answer for one way to do that.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the solution must be OSX Compatible. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
for origname in .[0-9A-Za-z]*
do   
    if [ -f "${origname}" ]; then
        # compute your newname how you want it
        mv "${origname}" "${newname}
    fi
done
```

You'll have to decide what you want your new names to be - you'll strip off the leading dot `'.'` but doing only what will probably collide with an existing .wma file with the same name, so maybe also append `.tmp` -- like:

```
.One Love.wma  --becomes-->  One Love.wma.tmp
```

Comment: This is perfect, i only need the pipeline. I was trying with sed, but i cannot strip off the leading dot. :S

for i in .[0-9A-Za-z]* ; do echo $i | sed 'regular expresion to strip off the leading dot' ; done

Comment: I had this, but i need fix the problem with the .wma :S
for i in .[0-9A-Za-z]* ; do N=`echo "$i" | sed "s/\.//g"`; mv "$i" "$N" ; done

Answer (score 1):

Use `prename` (`rename` on Debian-derived systems).

```
prename 's/^.//' .*.wma
```